# Limit Attributes in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to limit the attributes of "Promo" like i ust want to show the id and the title of promo
My code is:

```
  def show
if @job.present?
  if poster_authorize(@job)
  render json: @job, :include => [:tasks, :promo.as_json(only: [:title])], status: 200
  else
    json_forbidden("Forbidden")
  end
else
  json_not_found("Job Not Available")
end
end
```

Comment: Try `render json: @job, :only => [:id, :title], status: 200` more info about [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: but i want to show tasks also

Comment: i want to show the id and title of promo! the whole task but only limited promo

Comment: can you post what does it return right now?

Comment: It return everything of promo! All the fields!

Comment: What's your Job-Task-Promo Relation?

Comment: Job have task and promo

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 render json: @job.to_json( include: { [:tasks, promo: { only: [:id, :title]}]}), status: 200
```

Comment: it saying "Cannot clone symbol"

Comment: @NickBb : updated answer now try and let me know if any issue

Comment: > syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...job.to_json( include: { :tasks, promo: { only: [:id, :title]...
...                               ^
/home/bilal/goget-web/app/controllers/api/v2/jobs_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
... promo: { only: [:id, :title]}}), status: 200

Comment: `job.to_json( include: { :tasks, promo: { only: [:id, :title]}}), status: 200` works?

Comment: > syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...job.to_json( include: { :tasks, promo: { only: [:id, :title]...
...                               ^
/home/bilal/goget-web/app/controllers/api/v2/jobs_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
... promo: { only: [:id, :title]}}), status: 200

Comment: Do i need srilizers ?

Comment: `job.to_json( include: { [:tasks, promo: { only: [:id, :title]}]}), status: 200`

Comment: what if i want to show all attributes of a model:  ((( attributes :id, :promo_id))) i dont want to user this and want to show all from the model ? how ?

Comment: @NickBb : Can you be please more specific. show me method and where you want to display which data?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json), you can do this:

```
render json: @job.as_json(include: {:tasks, promo: {only: :title} }), status: 200
```